# Show partial view on button click mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out mvc, so I have problem...
I have this model:

```
public class Company
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and controller:

```
public ActionResult EditCompany()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Edit Company Page";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PartialEditCompany()
        {
            DataSet dataSet = client.SelectCompanies();
            ObservableCollection<Company> inventoryList = new ObservableCollection<Company>();
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                inventoryList.Add(new Company
                {
                    ID = (String)dataRow["ID"],
                    Symbol = (String)dataRow["Symbol"],
                    Description = (String)dataRow["Description"]
                });
            }
            return PartialView(inventoryList);
        }
```

and view EditCompany:

```
@model Test.Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditCompany";
    }

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>

    $('#loadData').click(function () {
        $('#partial').load('/HomeController/PartialEditCompany/');
    });

</script>

<div id="stylized2" class="myform">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCompany", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "insertcompanyform" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="first">@Html.Label("ID:")
            </td>
            <td class="second">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="first">
                @Html.Label("Symbol:")
            </td>
            <td class="second">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Symbol)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">
                @Html.Label("Description:")
            </td>
            <td class="second">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
                    <td class="third"><input type="button" value="Traži" id="loadData" /></td>
                    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="partial"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and finnaly partialview PartialEditCompany:

```
@using System.Web.Helpers

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@Html.WebGrid()
```

What I want to do is on button click (with id=loadData) to call partial view that will put grid into div tag (with id=parital). Please help! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as I can't comment here are some points I use to call partial views

1. If you are using a "main view" or a "shared view", you only need to define the scripts on the main view, not in your partial.
2. If you want a partial view to be loaded on click without any parameter you can call it and "hide it"

**View**

```
<div id="partial" style="display: none">
    @{Html.RenderAction("PartialEditCompany"); }
</div>
```

Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult PartialEditCompany()
    {
        //stuff you need and then return the partial view 
        //I recommend using "" quotes for a partial view
        return PartialView("inventoryList");
    }
```

And then if you want to have your partial view show on click you only display the div containing the div.

---

But if you want to use your partial view with parameters you can do the following

Javascript

```
 function getview(parameter){
         var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PartialEditCompany", "Controller", new { parameterID = "-parameter" }))";
         url = url.replace("-parameter", parameter);
         $('#partial').load(url);



        /*Better code by October 11, 2017, you can use this instead of the 3 lines on top*/
        /*
         var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PartialEditCompany", "Controller", new { parameterID = "-parameter" }))";
         url = url.replace("-parameter", parameter);
         $.ajax({
             url: url, 
             type: "GET", 
             cache: false, 
             success: function(result){
                  $("#partial").html(result)
             },
             error: function(){
                 //handle your error here
             }
         });
        */
 }
```

With javascript you can call a partial view and pass the parameter to the controller. Of course you don't specify if you need parameters or not, but here are both solutions I use with partial views. And you call your javascript function onclick event if you want or as you may like. (or using data-attr on the tag, and the with javascript or jquery on the click event, get that data-attr value without creating, this could be the unobtrusive way)

```
<input type="button" value="Traži" id="loadData" onclick='getview(parameter)' />
```

Hope this help a little about partial views.